# The login form doesn't work at all (using flask) in cs50 web pset 1

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I'm trying to create a login form that checks the existence of an account via a username and a password i've tried some stuff but don't seem to be able to get it to work

```
<form id="signupform" action="{{url_for  ('login') }}" method="post">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" name="username" >
          </div>


        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password (8 chars min)" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" name="password" " >
          </div>


        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
            We'll never share your info with anyone else.<br>
            <a href="signuppage">    No account? sign up here!</a>
        </small>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

    </form>
```

this is the the form ^^

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session ,render_template , request
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/home" , methods=["POST"])
def login():

    # request username and password

    username=request.form.get("username")
    password=request.form.get("password")

    #check if account exists

    account= db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password ",
    {"username":username , "password":password }).fetchone()

    if account is None:
        return render_template("loginerror.html")
    else:
        return render_template("homepage.html")
```

and this is the flask app^^

the database is also linked correctly so idk

i'm so lost, any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>`
. From [MDN button element doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

> **type**
>
> The default behavior of the button. Possible values are:
>
> - **submit:** The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified for buttons
>     associated with a , or if the attribute is an empty or invalid
>     value.
> - **reset:** The button resets all the controls to their initial values, like . (This behavior tends to annoy
>     users.)
> - **button:** The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when pressed by default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the
>     element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified the error you got (and you should have to), but I'm pretty sure that the form you made is correct (there's a trailling quotation mark at the end of your password field)

There is no `methods=["POST","GET"])` in your `@app.route("/home" , methods=["POST"])` snippet.  Currently, you code is posting his result but cannot get the page back. When you are using post, you are sending information to the server, but it's NOT a "GET" request which mean it won't change your URL or search for a new one. You should implements a function that check if you are logged in and if so, do a "window.location.href = myserver.com/home" (in js).

Also, I suggest you two things. First, use a already made login engine like `flask-login` you will save time. Also, if you don't need to access the model by another procces simultaneously, use the `flask-sqlalchemy` library. It's a nice wrapper that reduce the code you have to write

Comment: i'm not really getting errors back i fill the form sumbit it and nothing happens don't even recieve the post request ,using a post request then using render_template was in the source code for the course several times so idk what's wrong with it, also doesn't this count as a function that checks login and then opens another page based on that sorry im really really slow if u could dumb it down for me i'd really appreciate that